# Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make a plane propeller spin when e is pressed but i can't use bool in transform.Translate

here my code

```
public class SpinPropeller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 300.0f;
    bool switchInput = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            bool switchInput = true;
        }

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * switchInput);
    }
}
```

i tried different operators but it was the same result and i'm new so that's even more hard

Comment: Do you want no spin when `switchInput` is false, and spin when `switchInput` is true? Then just make a condition `if (switchInput) transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);`

Comment: Note that your switchInput in that Update method is local to the if-statement, hiding the class-level field. Remove the "bool"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need "switchInput" variable in this context. Just use:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

If You want to turn on/off propeller rotation with pressing 'E', then rewrite Your code using GetKeyDown method (instead of GetKey), like this:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
        switchInput = !switchInput // '!' operator changes bool value to opposite
    }
    if (switchInput) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```